# Changing name when a domain holder is a citizen of one country; possible problems

Tags: security, domain-registrar, internationalization, name, icann

I am a citizen of Israel and I desire to generally cut all ties with it besides generally with family, friends and job.
Currently I live in another state as a temporary resident.

I consider changing my last name in generally all of Israel's systems (formal name change procedure):

- As of 11/11/19, Israeli citizens can change their first and/or last name inside and outside its borders (outside in its general consulates).
  Inside it can take up to one month and outside it can take up to one year
- As of 11/11/19, a new Israeli passport will always include previous passport numbers (if there were any) for seven years, and previous passport names (if there were any) for seven years

---

I have a website to which I consider changing domain from *ccTLD* (`.co.il`) to *gTLD* (`.com`).

I consider buying a *gTLD* domain via an ICANN-authorized international domain registrar such as *Namecheap* or *Godaddy* **and only after some time** do the aforementioned formal name change and getting a new passport.

Is there an ICANN-obligatory standard procedure bestowed upon such international domain registrars, to update both its database and ICANN's database, per being asked to do a name change by a domain holder (who made a formal name change)?
Also, does inquiring such procedure puts the inquiring customer in any risk to lose the domain by some lawful or bureaucratic reason?

Comment: Have you read the ICANN official documentation on the same? https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/ownership-2013-05-03-en

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "software fraud".  Can you explain that more?

Comment: @Anuvesh not until you attached it; as I understand from it - informing the registrant, in this case - whether Israeli Internet (ISOC-IL) Association or supervised registrant under ISOC-IL is what people would need to do in the case described in question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I meant in the broad sense, and in particular as a fraud of a human of another human through the mediation of a software, but I have just totally removed this part.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I edited the question based on my understanding of the motives to your massive edit that at least in part conflicted with my original intents.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear for the following reasons:

> I have a website to which I consider changing the domain from CCTLD to NCCTLD.

There is no such change, if I understood you correctly (and ncctld is not a globally known acronym). You are registering a new domain name under a new TLD. Whatever other domain you may have already in other TLDs is irrelevant.

> Say I buy an NCCTLD domain via an ICANN-authorized international domain register

That is also something that does not make a lot of sense. ICANN regulates the gTLD world. It has no impact on what happens for ccTLDs. ccTLDs are each under their own rules. You do not even specify which TLDs you are speaking about so it is impossible to give you advises. There are no "standard" procedure for anything across all TLDs.

> Is there an ICANN-obligatory standard procedure

No, certainly not in ccTLD. In gTLDs, there are exceptions, but otherwise you can change the registrant of a domain name freely. There is an ICANN procedure on that that just mandates some emails to be sent by registrars etc.
Also there are domain privacy/proxy services where another names instead of yours appear to be the owner of the domain.

But all of that, to reply properly, depends on the TLD and the registrar.

In short, start at least by stating the TLD that you are considering, otherwise it is impossible to reply to you.

Comment: Hello; I downvoted because it seemed to me you "blame" me for not mentioning the ccTLD (thanks for correcting my phrasing) which is something I clearly don't want to do; I did more phrasing fixes per other parts from your answer. Also, AFAIK, ccTLDs should be internationally recognized somewhere - if it's not ICANN than I don't know who is this authority.

Comment: Also, regarding `No, certainly not in ccTLD` I didn't thought for a moment there is --- I know that ccTLDs are handled by specific internet associations; if I would know why you thought otherwise I will gladly edit that part of the question as well.

Comment: "which is something I clearly don't want to do;" then reply to your question is just: No, there is no standard procedure. And then your question is not very relevant for a Q/A site, it won't help you nor anyone else...

Comment: "I know that ccTLDs are handled by specific internet associations"  each ccTLD is run by its governing country delegating it to "someone". Hence nothing standard. So "No" is the only possible reply to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making it a bit hard on yourself .. if the .com domain is available just buy it and register it with your new identity.

for your old domain use domain privacy service to hide your name on that domain and redirect it 301 to your new domain, basically you will need to do that if you want to continue the same SERP exposure and not starting from the ground up

Comment: Welcome to webmasters. As considerate as it might be, but this does not attempt to provide an answer to the question asked. It is more of an opinion which is not accepted as an answer at Webmasters. I request to make some edits in order to cover the topic of the question. Thanks.

Comment: you can include it as a comment or remove it if you find it is not a useful solution

Comment: Hi, I miss how the answer fully address my problem but anyway I can't hide identity for Israeli domains --- it's against Israeli (dictatorial) law.